# RWD - Element doesn't auto hide

Tags: responsive-design

I'm having a trouble with RWD. My '+Menu' can auto hide when it fit larger screen but my 'menu-item' isn't auto hide when it fit larger screen.

This is link to jsfiddle:

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/ux3pe797/`
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this problem.

The problem because javascript will set inline css style for html element when @media query don't affect them.

Solution:

Add an class named 'active' with 'display: block' and change element style to 'active' class.